# View layout weirdness

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, layoutparams

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, please?

[image]

What I'm trying to do is get them to all align centered, regardless of how many there are. It works lovely for quite a few, and even works with only 1 more, but 4 seems to do this. I'm adding them in code, here:

```
    LinearLayout guessHolders = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.guessHolders);
    guessHolders.removeAllViews();
    currentLetterPosition = 0;

    final Bitmap emptyLetterHolder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.letter_holder);

    for(int i=0; i<Globals.mUser.getLevel().getSolution().length(); i++)
    {
        final EmptyLetter tmp = new EmptyLetter(this, i);
        tmp.setImageBitmap(emptyLetterHolder);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Globals.defaultLetterSizes[mBlockSize], 
                Globals.defaultLetterSizes[mBlockSize], 1);
        parms.weight = 1;
        parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        tmp.setLayoutParams(parms);         
        tmp.setAdjustViewBounds(false);         
        tmp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("PP2", tmp.getId() + " << the clicked empty letter holder id");
                currentLetterPosition = tmp.getId();
                tmp.setImageBitmap(emptyLetterHolder);
                setChosenLetter(tmp.getId(), '\u0000');
            }
        });

        currentEmpties.add(tmp);            
        guessHolders.addView(tmp);
    }
```

I've tried setting `gravity`, `weightsum`, `width` and `height` of the box views as well as the parent container `LinearLayout`, but nothing seems to shift them.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When the **weight** is set, the weighted dimension must be **0dp** wide/tall

Comment: try RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and see what happens

Comment: RelativeLayouts can't use the **weight** attribute

Comment: If I set the width/height to 0dp nothing shows at all - I didn't think Relatives could use weighting.

Comment: @DerGolem i know, he would have to change the entire code, if he wanted to use RelativeLayout, anyway glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. With the following:

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Globals.defaultLetterSizes[mBlockSize], 
                Globals.defaultLetterSizes[mBlockSize], 0);
        parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        tmp.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

So, I set the **weighting** to zero and leave the rest to the OS. Works for all of them now. Marvelous.

Cheers